How to Create a Slide-in Animation on macOS Using AppKit
I'm attempting to create a slide-in animation for a window on macOS using AppKit, but I'm encountering some issues with the animation behaviors.

Animating by Changing the X Coordinate: When I animate the window's x-coordinate from "-width" to "0", the window will initially appears on the left screen and then moves to the right.
Animating by Changing the X Coordinate

Animating by Changing the Width: If I try to animate by changing the window's width, the contentView gets cropped during the animation.
Animating by Changing the Width


Here is the example code I'm using to implement the animation:
let contentView = ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
let dockWindow = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 900),
    styleMask: [.nonactivatingPanel],
    backing: .buffered,
    defer: false
)

if let focusedScreen = NSScreen.main {
                let screenHeight = focusedScreen.visibleFrame.height
                let targetY = (screenHeight - dockWindow.frame.height) / 2 + focusedScreen.visibleFrame.origin.y
                let targetRect = NSRect(
                    x: focusedScreen.visibleFrame.minX, 
                    y: targetY, 
                    width: dockWindow.frame.width,
                    height: dockWindow.frame.height
                )
                
                let initialRect = NSRect(x: focusedScreen.visibleFrame.minX,
                                         y: targetY,
                                         width: 0, //animate by change the width of the window
                                         height: dockWindow.frame.height)
                dockWindow.setFrame(initialRect, display: true)
                
                NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
                    context.duration = 0.2
                    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
                    dockWindow.setFrame(targetRect, display: true)
                } completionHandler: {
                    self.isAnimating = false
                }
            } 
else {
                isAnimating = false
            }

I'm looking for suggestions on how to create a smooth slide-in effect without the issues mentioned. Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

An alternative is to use SwiftUI with all the good animation features, it is supposed to be compatible with AppKit.
See also: AppKit Integration

Thanks for the suggestion! I'm already using SwiftUI, but I'm not too familiar with AppKit or SwiftUI. I'm having trouble figuring out how to animate on the "Window" part.

Instead of animating the slide in of the entire window, I would recommend using a clear borderless transparent window and animating in a subview within the content view using layout constraints.
Example Storyboard layout:

Constraints:

So initially the Slide In View's leading constraint is negative its width (-250). This will push it out of the visible window and out of view completely. Because any view content outside of their window won't be visible, this will avoid the issue you were running into with it displaying on the second screen left of the one you were trying to slide into.
To make the Window transparent/borderless use these settings:

uncheck show title bar in the storyboard
Check full size content view
uncheck shadow
programmatically set isOpaque to false
programmatically set backgroundColor to .clear

Once we're ready to slide in animate, change the leading constraint's constant to 0 (hugging the left hand side of the window) and then animate laying out the view to slide it in.
Example code for the SlideInViewController:
import Cocoa

class SlideInViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet public var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    @IBOutlet public var slideInView: NSView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.slideInView?.wantsLayer = true
        self.slideInView?.layer?.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    public func slideIn() {
        if let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame {
            let centeredY = (screenFrame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height) / 2 + screenFrame.origin.y
            let windowFrame = NSRect(
                x: screenFrame.minX,
                y: centeredY,
                width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                height: self.view.frame.size.height
            )
            self.view.window?.isOpaque = false
            self.view.window?.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.view.window?.setFrame(windowFrame, display: true)
            self.view.window?.orderFront(nil)
            self.leadingConstraint?.constant = 0.0
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
                context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
                context.duration = 2.0
                self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
            } completionHandler: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)) {
                    self.slideOut()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func slideOut() {
        if let slideInViewWidth = self.slideInView?.frame.size.width {
            self.leadingConstraint?.constant = -slideInViewWidth
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
                context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
                context.duration = 2.0
                self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
            } completionHandler: {
                self.view.window?.orderOut(nil)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

Example call site in AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let slideInViewController = (storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "slideInWindow") as? NSWindowController)?.contentViewController as? SlideInViewController
        slideInViewController?.slideIn()
    }

Example of it in action:


That's a great idea! Would you also be able to provide an example of how to achieve this using SwiftUI?

I've figured it out. Thanks again.
